# Render animation in png's give same frames

Tags: rendering, animation

When I render an animation in multiple png's blender outputs all the frames. The only problem is, all the png output files are the same. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thx for the file, found the problem:

two things:
1. bake cloth simulation: "Bake All Dynamics", otherwise eevee wont simulate it as  Blender would do it by pressing play in 3D View.
2. Your Render step in the Output-Menue was at 1000, so you would only get 1 frame. Just put it to 1 and everything should work fine.

just for completness: i used "blender-2.80.0-git.957b4547aeeb-windows64" build to test it.

Comment: I have 1 camera and the camera is pinned. It's a flag animation. it's for a school project.
Here is a link to the file. https://drive.google.com/open?id=13wAES2o-U6B-OIlS-tKU6wnmrDjDWR16

Comment: updated the answer